# Visualization of streaming data coming with very high velocity

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, apache-storm

I am using Twitter Storm for my real time analytics over streaming high velocity/big data. Now  I have no clue as to how can I go on visualizing the data on a browser in an effective manner. I mean the velocity at which Storm is processing is really really fast and storm is working on a cluster. I just came across the combination of Node.js and D3.js for solving this display problem. As I am not from UI nor javascript world so just wanted to know am I heading in the right direction? Can somebody explain in simple terms as to what the combination would provide me with?

Comment: You've sort of just thrown names of technologies in the air. This isn't answerable without more detail on what you're actually trying to do. What data do you want to show? How close to real-time do you need it? Are you targeting browsers that support WebSockets?

Comment: +1 for counteracting the negative vote given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well a couple of days of research on the various javascript buzzwords led me to design a solution where Storm publishes data to Redis & Node.js is a subscriber for Redis (pub/sub). Node.js uses Socket.IO to send data further to the D3.js working on various clients. Well learning about these interesting technologies was a good break from the trifecta (Kafka, Storm, Cassandra) I was tied up with for a couple of months.